# How to launch own application from overlay window

Tags: flutter

I am using `flutter_overlay_window` to display an overlay on top of other apps. I was wondering if it is any way to launch the app/go to the main screen by pressing the buttons that are inside the overlay window?
I tried using `auto_route` to redirect the overlay window to the main screen:

```
overlay_window.dart:
TextButton(onPressed: () {
                      context.router.push(AlarmRoute());
                    }
```

I get error `AutoRouter operation requested with a context that does not include an AutoRouter.`